# Starcraft II on linux

Tags: wine, games

I have installed wine and am trying to play Starcraft II on fedora 21. It loads fine but none of the graphics are properly displayed in the background after the game starts and when I try to enter into an online match the game crashes. I am assuming it may have something to do with an outdated driver in for my GPU, the Radeon HD7850, however I am new to Linux and I'm not sure how to update the drivers in Wine.